# Trying to prove that the commutator subgroup of the free group with two generators contain more than just commutators

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

So I am trying to show that the commutator subgroup of the free group with two generators $F_2=\langle a, b \rangle$ contain more than just commutators. That is, there exists $\sigma \in [F_2, F_2]$ such that $\sigma\neq \alpha \beta \alpha^{-1} \beta^{-1} \forall \alpha ,\beta \in F_2$.

One problem is given $\sigma$ it is hard to rule out all possibilities. For example, it is hard to check if $aba^{-1}b^{-1}aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ is a commutator, since 
\begin{align*}
\alpha \beta & = \alpha\mathbf{(aa)(a^{-1}a^{-1})}\beta\\
&= \alpha(a \mathbf{b b^{-1}} a)(a^{-1}a^{-1})\beta,\\
\end{align*}
which does not have the expression $\alpha c c^{-1}\beta$, which seems to imply that we cannot reduce it easily.

Any source/ reference will be helpful.

Comment: If you can find a concrete two generator group in which the order of the commutator subgroup is larger than the number of commutators, there must be an element of that group which is not a commutator. The group itself will be a homomorphic image of your free group, and if the elements which map to non-commutators under the homomorphism were commutators in the free group the homomorphism would show that they became commutators in the image - contradiction. That would seem to be an easier way to proceed than doing calculations in he free group.

Comment: The smallest groups $G$ in which not every element of $[G,G]$ is a commutator have order $96$, and are SmallGroup(96,3). and SmallGroup(96,203). The first of these is a $2$-generator group (the second one is not), which provides an indirect proof of your result.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thanks. That would work. But I am still interested in a proof that deals with the non-unique representations of the elements.

Comment: Google scl (stable commutator length).